# adding arguments to $_POST?

Tags: php, post

I've been attempting to use `$_GET` to try and manage my log file of flagged accounts but this new situation it's not exactly working.

```
if (isset($_GET['marked'])) {
        if ($_GET['marked'] == 'read') {
            if (isset($_POST['mark'])) {
                foreach ($_POST['mark'] as $mark) {
                    mysql_query("UPDATE logged SET status = '1' WHERE timeLogged = $mark");
                    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=/admincpanel/flagged.php'>";
                }
            }
        }
        else if ($_GET['marked'] == 'unread') {
            if (isset($_POST['mark'])) {
                foreach ($_POST['mark'] as $mark) {
                    mysql_query("UPDATE logged SET status = '0' WHERE timeLogged = $mark");
                    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=/admincpanel/flagged.php'>";
                }
            }
        }
        else if ($_GET['marked'] == 'save') {
            if (isset($_POST['mark'])) {
                foreach ($_POST['mark'] as $mark) {
                    mysql_query("UPDATE logged SET status = '2' WHERE timeLogged = $mark");
                    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=/admincpanel/flagged.php'>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and I have the buttons: `Mark as <a href=\"?marked=read\" onclick=\"submitForm();\"><i>read</i></a><a href=\"?marked=unread\" onclick=\"submitForm();\">/unread</a>`

I'm using checkboxes to select what rows I want and before with no $_GET the default submitForm(); worked just fine.

This worked: `Mark as <a href=\"#\" onclick=\"submitForm();\"><i>read</i></a>`

```
    if (isset($_POST['mark'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['mark'] as $mark) {
            mysql_query("UPDATE logged SET status = '1' WHERE timeLogged = $mark");
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=/admincpanel/flagged.php'>";
        }
    }
```

How can I get my other markers *(read,unread,save)* to work? Submitting the form and getting results seems the only work with `$_POST` so I must need to add more arguments to `$_POST` right?

if it helps any this is the javascript:

```
function submitForm() {
    document.logs.submit();
}
```

To sum it up, I'm trying to make read update status to 1, unread status 0, and save status 2.  And using `$_GET` isn't working--or I'm doing it wrong.  So what can I do to make this work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hy
Try add a hidden field in the form:

`<input type="hidden" name="marked" id="marked" value="" />`

Then, the buttons:

`Mark as

```
<a href=\"?marked=read\" onclick=\"submitForm('read');\"><i>read</i></a><a href=\"?marked=unread\" onclick=\"submitForm('unread');\">/unread</a>`
```

Then the JavaScript function:

```
function submitForm(mark) {
  document.getElementById('marked').value = mark;
  document.logs.submit();
}`
```

Then, in the php script use $_REQUEST['marked'] insted of $_GET

Answer (score 1):

The `href="?marked=read"` is never sent to the server because you're submitting the form instead.

To resolve the problem you could add an argument to your `submitForm()` function and store this argument as the value of a hidden form input named 'marked'.

Like this:

```
Mark as <a href="#" onclick="submitForm('read')">read</a>
```

and

```
function submitForm(marked) {
  // TODO: Setup hidden input field with the marked argument
  document.logs.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the php code, a bit cleaner and concise:

```
if (isset($_GET['marked'])) {
    if ($_GET['marked') == 'read')
        $status = 1;
    elseif ($_GET['marked'] == 'unread')
        $status = 0;
    else
        $status = 1;
    }
if (isset($_POST['mark'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['mark'] as $mark) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE logged SET status = $status WHERE timeLogged = $mark");
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=/admincpane/flagged.php'>";
        }
    }
```